# My relation doesn't reflect in my database. symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to add a table and make a relationship.
But my code does not work.

```
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ecb\UserBundle\Entity\ColoproctologyInfo", mappedBy="userId", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $coloproctologyInfo;
```

```
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ColoproctologyInfo")
 */
class ColoproctologyInfo extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ecb\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="coloproctologyInfo", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $userId;
```

And I executed this command.

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --force
```

But my table does not have a foreign key.
What is the reason..?

Comment: Have you ran `php bin/console make:migrations and php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`? `make:migrations` will create a migration file in your `/migrations` folder, `doctrine:migrations:migrate` will update the database with foreign keys etc if needed.

Comment: Might be that the `@ORM\Column` is conflicting, I think you should replace it with `@ORM\JoinColumn`

Comment: Also use `php bin/console make:entity` to create the relation. When it asks for the *type* use *relation* it will guide you. Much easier than manually creating it.